# create object with proporties

Tags: c++

How to create an object in C++ with proporties?

If the object is an rectangle I want to access the height and the width like this

```
int height = obj.height;
int width = obj.width;
```

The object is returned by a function.. So what is the return type of the function?

Comment: `struct rectangle { int height; int width; };`

Comment: What do you mean by "proporties"? Something like prop**e**rties in C#?

Comment: The return type of the function is your rectangle type.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Rectangle`:

```
class Rectangle {
private:
    int height;
    int width;
public:
    Rectangle(int h, int w) : height(h), width(w) {} // constructor to initialize width and height

    void getHeight() { return height; } // public getters but private attributes to stick to the encapusaltion 
    void getWidth() { return width; } 
};
```

Have a function returning a rectangle:

```
Rectangle doSomething() { // the return type is an instance of the class Rectangle
    Rectangle r(2, 3); // create a rectangle with a height of 2 and a width of 3 
    return r; // return the created object
}

int main()
{
    Rectangle r = doSomething(); // call your function
    cout << r.getHeight() << "  " << r.getWidth() << endl; // prompt width and height
}
```

If you want to access `width` and `height` via `r.width` and `r.height` change the access specifier `private` to `public`. Then you will not need the getters anymore.